# How to import google-cloud-lanugage on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

For the purpose of sentiment analysis, I have installed the google-cloud-language through pip, obtained the json authentication and everything just work fine on shell and Pycharm.

I tried conda install for google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-storage and google-cloud-core but still failed to make it work.

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA9uavDW1yo) so I know using google NLP on Jupyter should be possible.

Please Help.

Comment: You will need to edit your question to include output of the command(s) that failed. Also, the question title seems a bit off - did you mean "How to import google-cloud-lanugage on Jupyter Notebook?"

Answer (score 1):

Now I know it.

```
! pip install --upgrade requests google-cloud-language
! pip show google.cloud.language
#! pip show requests
```

Comment: Hi Lee, After I ran the two commands you recommended on terminal, I still can not run my jupyter notebook which calls google.cloud. Could you please give me more details on how you solved the problem? Thanks 11     from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
     12     client = speech.SpeechClient()
     13 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

Comment: I also ran the two commands on jupyter notebook, it did not work either. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Hi Lee, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!